# How to convert a string (button) to number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, buttonclick

How to convert a string to an integer in JavaScript?

```
const secrectNumber = 4;

button class="btn-number">01</button

button class="btn-number">02</button

button class="btn-number">03</button

button class="btn-number">04</button

button class="btn-number">05</button

$(".btn-number").click(function (e) {
   if ($(this).text() === secretNumber) {
       
   }

}
```

How do I convert button is string to number in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve this in two ways **:**

- By using strict equality operator (`===`), In this case you have to cast the string into Number by using `Number()` or `parseInt()`.
- By using equality operator (`==`) checks whether its two operands are equal, returning a Boolean result.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const secrectNumber = 4;

$(".btn-number").click(function (e) {
  // By using === operator
  if(Number(e.target.innerText) === secrectNumber) {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
  }
  
  // By using == operator
  if(e.target.innerText == secrectNumber) {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-number">01</button>

<button class="btn-number">02</button>

<button class="btn-number">03</button>

<button class="btn-number">04</button>

<button class="btn-number">05</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

parseInt will turn string into int

parseInt('1') = 1

Comment: If you're using `parseInt` you really should [add the radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#parameters). It won't necessarily always default to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string to an integer either by using the `Number` wrapper, like so:

`Number('01') // Returns 1`

Or by using parseInt and passing a radix parameter.
Assuming you're working in base-10:

`parseInt('11', 10) // Returns 11`.